# How do i remove :: command in vim

Tags: vim

:: is used to execute command in command line mode.
I wanna remove that.

I tried the way below.

```
map! :: <nop>
unmap! ::
cmap :: <nop>
cnoremap :: <nop>
cunmap ::
```

But nothing works.

How do I remove that :: command?
plz help me. ~(._.)~

Comment: The _normal mode_ command `:` is used to enter _command-line mode_; there's no `::` command (though the second `:` is a harmless no-op). **Why** do you want to turn off that very valuable mode? (How would you save and quit, if not via `:wq`?!)

Comment: oh, I made a mistake. I wanna map :: to <ESC> in command line mode.
so, I mapped in a way that [cnoremap :: <ESC>], But it did not work. I press ::, command is executed. That's why I asked.. Do you know why that? Thank you answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're strugging with the following special behavior documented under `:help c_Esc`:

```
<Esc>       When typed and 'x' not present in 'cpoptions', quit
            Command-line mode without executing.  In macros or when 'x'
            present in 'cpoptions', start entered command.
```

To avoid executing the command-line in a macro / mapping, use `<C-C>` instead:

```
:cnoremap :: <C-c>
```